# Flash AS3 ERROR: 1106 operand of increment must be a reference

Tags: actionscript-3

1106 operand of increment must be a reference.

```
this.format.size = Object(Number(this.format.size)--);
```

Answer (score 1):

First: where you're create format variable?

Second: Line

```
 this.format.size = Object(Number(this.format.size)--);
```

doesn't have sense.  When  decrement is used as a postfix operator, the expression's value is returned before the postfix operator is processed.
Use:

```
format.size -= 1;
```

or

```
format.size--;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
var tmpNum:Number = Number(this.format.size);
this.format.size  = Object(tmpNum--);
```

!! But why not to use:

```
this.format.size--;
```

Answer (score 0):

this.format.size is null or undefined or size is not a property of format ( i.e. this.format is null )

Answer (score 0):

The cast/conversion to Number is to blame. `--` is shorthand for `-= 1`. So it needs something to store the new value to. But the Number conversion returns a value, not a reference, so what you've written there translates to:

```
//let's say this.format.size holds the value '5'
this.format.size = Object(5 -= 1);
```

And you can't store a value in a value obviously.

If you're not 100% sure this.format.size returns a number then the easy way out is:

```
this.format.size = parseInt( this.format.size ) -1;
```

But obviously it would be better to validate the value that is stored into format.size upfront.